# Want to use Angularjs validation instead of Browser validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms, validation

I have a form which holds two ng-forms where i am validating the input. I have two questions regarding my forms.

1) In the input Company I want to validate for the minlength, but my approach seems not to work. How can i solve this problem?

2) I want to use Angularjs validation with my error messages but the browser automatically shows "This input is invalid" AND Internet Explorer does not validate at all. Where is my fault? I already tried nonvalidate and ng-required but then my form does submit without validation.

Here is the plunkr link : [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DvEmES?p=preview)

Thanks in advance,
YB

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.billingAdrEqualsShippingAdr = false;
   
   $scope.confirmBillingEqualsShipping = true;
   $scope.changeBillingAddress = false;
   
   $scope.shippingAddress = {};
   $scope.billingAddress = {};

   $scope.setBillingAddress = function (){
     $scope.changeBillingAddress = true;
    $scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
   };
   
   $scope.cancelBillingAddress = function (){
     $scope.changeBillingAddress = false;
    $scope.billingAddress = $scope.shippingAddress;
   };

   $scope.openCompanyModal = function (company){
    $scope.billingAddress = company;
    $scope.shippingAddress = company;
   };

  $scope.submit = function (){
    console.log("Form submitted");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="addressForm" ng-submit="submit()">
      <div ng-form="shippingForm">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3 class="form-group">
                      <label>Lieferadresse</label>
                  </h3>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Salutation</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <select name="salutation" ng-model="shippingAddress.salutation" class="form-control" ng-change="refreshBillingAddress()" ng-required="true">
                      <option></option>
                      <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                      <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                  </select>
                  <span ng-show="submitted && shippingForm.salutation.$error.required"></span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Firsname</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="prename" ng-model="shippingAddress.prename" ng-required="true" class="form-control" ng-change="refreshBillingAddress()"/>
                  <span ng-show="submitted && shippingForm.prename.$error.required">Required</span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Lastname</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="surname" ng-model="shippingAddress.surname" required="" class="form-control" ng-change="refreshBillingAddress()"/>
                  <span ng-show="submitted && shippingForm.surname.$error.required">Required</span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Company</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" name="company" ng-model="shippingAddress.company" required="" ng-minlength="10" class="form-control" ng-change="refreshBillingAddress()"/>
                  <span ng-show="submitted && shippingForm.company.$error.required">Required</span>
                  <span ng-show="submitted && shippingForm.company.$error.minlength">Minlength = 10</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div >
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3 class="form-group">
                  <label>Rechnungsadresse</label>
                  <div ng-click="setBillingAddress()" ng-show="changeBillingAddress === false" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Ändern</div>
                  <div ng-click="cancelBillingAddress()" ng-show="changeBillingAddress === true" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Abbrechen</div>
              </h3>
          </div>
          <div ng-show="changeBillingAddress == false" class="row">
              <div class="col-md-offset-1">Identisch mit Lieferadresse</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="changeBillingAddress == true">
          <div style="margin-top: 5px">
              <div ng-form="billingForm">
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label>Salutation</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <select name="salutation" ng-model="billingAddress.salutation" ng-required="changeBillingAddress == true" class="form-control">
                              <option></option>
                              <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                              <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                          </select>
                          <span ng-show="submitted" class="help-block">Pflichtfeld</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label>Firstname</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="text" name="prename" ng-model="billingAddress.prename" ng-required="changeBillingAddress == true" class="form-control"/>
                          <span ng-show="submitted && billingForm.prename.required" class="help-block">Pflichtfeld</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label>Lastname</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="text" name="surname" ng-model="billingAddress.surname" ng-required="changeBillingAddress == true" class="form-control"/>
                          <span ng-show="submitted && billingForm.surname.$error.required"></span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label>Company</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="text" name="company" ng-model="billingAddress.company" ng-required="changeBillingAddress == true" class="form-control"/>
                          <span ng-show="submitted && billingForm.company.$error.required"></span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div style="padding-top: 1em" class="col-md-12">
              <button ng-click="previousTab(0)" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Back</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Next</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have nested forms using the same `ng-submit` method, not sure how that's going to work. Also, you have defined the form name here: `<div ng-form="shppingForm" ng-submit="submit()">`, but it has a typo with a missing "i". To prevent browser validation use the `novalidate` directive on your forms.

Comment: I corrected the typo now and removed the ng-submit from both nested forms. But it still doesnt work. I used two nested forms because I didnt know how to handle this use case otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your plunker, i corrected some parts (until Rechnungsaddresse):

http://plnkr.co/edit/luVETXTVCf2PkNAKzK1Z?p=preview

I guess you can use `<form name="addressForm"...` or `<div ng-form="addressForm"`
but both seems to make problems.

`submitted` was never set, so i added it in the way i guess you intended